# Поменять местами соседние слова

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

```
string text = "Один два три четыре пять шесть семь восемь девять десять одиннадцать";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\w+)(.*?)(\w+)");
Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(text, "$3$2$1"));
```

С таким кодом возникает проблема с последним словом:

> два Один четыре три шесть пять восемь семь десять девять ьодиннадцат

Comment: Можно явно указать пробелы: `@"(\w+)(\s+)(\w+)"`. Или, если могут быть и другие знаки, то любые небуквенные символы: `@"(\w+)(\W+)(\w+)"`

Comment: Важно не только явно указывать тип символов, но и их минимальное количество. Так как `.*?` находит совпадение пустой строки, второй `\w+` просто "отбирает" последний символ у первого.  `@"(\w+)(\W+)(\w+)"` - решение.

Answer (score 1):

Старайтесь писать такие регулярные выражения, в которых каждый следующий шаблон не находит совпадения, которое находит предыдущий. Таким образом, можно избежать множества проблем, как текущей, так и других (например, "catastrophic backtracking").

Посмотрите, к чему сводится оригинальное выражение *в случае, если на входе строка из цифробуквенных символов и символов подчёркивания*:

```
(\w+)(.*?)(\w+) => (\w+)(\w+) => (\w+)(\w)
```

Слово `одиннадцать` разбивается на `одиннадцат` и `ь`, так как первый `\w+` "забирает" все символы в слове, а затем "отдаёт" последний второй группе, `(\w)` (так как он должен "найти" хотя бы 1 символ.

Шаблон `(.*?)` находит любой символ, отличный от символа перехода на новую строку. Т.е. он находит те же символы, что и `\w`. Это не имеет смысла в данной ситуации: тут нужно найти **два** слова как минимум. Значит, между первым и вторым `\w+` должен быть шаблон, обратный `\w+`. Т.е. это либо `\W+` (1 и более символов, отличных от букв, цифр, символа подчеркивания и некоторых диакритических знаков, т.к. используется в .NET).

Используйте

```
var text = "Один два три четыре пять шесть семь восемь девять десять одиннадцать";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(text, @"(\w+)(\W+)(\w+)", "$3$2$1"));
```

[Демо регулярного выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5Cw%2B%29%28%5CW%2B%29%28%5Cw%2B%29&i=%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&r=%243%242%241)

**Бонус: поменять порядок слов** можно с помощью

```
var line = "Один два три четыре пять шесть семь восемь девять десять одиннадцать";
var result = string.Concat(Regex.Split(line, @"(\W+)").Reverse());
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

См. [демо онлайн](http://ideone.com/IuMKP8).